# Are there any multi-class classification techniques that do not involve the softmax?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, softmax

It seems that the softmax is basically a key component of multi-class classification. Does there exist any classifiers that do not rely on the softmax?

Comment: Are you restricting your classifiers to neural networks?

Comment: @Dave Hi, no. But I am not aware of any classifiers that does multi-class classification well outside of NNs.

Comment: Random forests, knn, naive bayes... all do multi class classification without softmax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random Forest

K-Nearest Neighbors

Support Vector Machines

Naïve Bayes

The reason why softmax is popular for the neural networks, however, is because it is the multi-class analogue of the inverse link function in logistic regression. Even in logistic regression, though, you can use other link functions, and I have my suspicions that this is generalizable to multi-class problems, too.